# Game graphics - Nvidia GPU Gems 3 DVD content

Tags: nvidia

The nvidia GPU Gems 3 chapters are available for free online, however there doesn't seem to be a download available for the DVD content which is supposed to contain source codes and samples and is supposed to accompany the book.

The book itself is not available for purchase anywhere (I live in germany, the only place I found it at was amazon, where it's being sold used for 200+ Euros). Other than that I could only find a kindle version, which, again, does not include the DVD content.

The book makes a lot of references to the DVD content and not having it at hand makes it rather difficult to follow it properly.

I've searched extensively, but I could only find the source codes for the old versions of the book, which are useless to me. I'm not looking for alternatives, but perhaps someone knows whether or not the DVD content is actually free as well, and if it is, where to get it, maybe I'm just missing something.